# How to Guess a number between 0-100:50?

Tags: python

Guess a number between 0 - 100: 50

```
import random
comGuess = random.randint(0,100)

while True:
        userGuess = int(input("Guess a number between 0-100:"))
        if userGuess > comGuess:
            print("Guess lower")
        elif userGuess > comGuess:
            print("Guess higher")
        else:
            print("Congratz, you have guessed the coorect number")
    break
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Thanks

Comment: there's a pretty obvious-looking indentation error. I don't immediately see the syntax error though. It'd be pretty self-evident if you included the traceback that Python gives you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an indentation problem (not Syntax). The `break` command should be at least at the level of your `if` but in your case, I guess it should be inside the else, in order to exit the infinite loop in case the user guessed correctly the number.

In addition, the first 2 conditions are identical. Probably you meant to:

```
import random
comGuess = random.randint(0,100)

while True:
    userGuess = int(input("Guess a number between 0-100:"))
    if userGuess < comGuess:
        print("Guess lower")
    elif userGuess > comGuess:
        print("Guess higher")
    else:
        print("Congratz, you have guessed the coorect number")
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code has indentation problems. Fix it and everything will work fine

```
import random
comGuess = random.randint(0,100)

while True:
    userGuess = int(input("Guess a number between 0-100:"))
    if userGuess > comGuess:
        print("Guess lower")
    elif userGuess > comGuess:
        print("Guess higher")
    else:
        print("Congratz, you have guessed the coorect number")
    break
```

Comment: Yeah the fact that the OQA reported a Syntax Error means that this isn't the problem. Thanks though!

Comment: Indentation Error is a Syntax error itself. issubclass(IndentationError, SyntaxError) would return True to you